# Email wont verify when using auto fill

Tags: jquery, forms, autofill, verify

My code wont recognise that an email has been entered when I use the autofill function.

```js
$(function() {

  var checkout_button_shown = false;
  
  // set all inputs to invalid background
  
  $('.form-control').css("background", "#FFF url('img/invalid.png') no-repeat right");

  function simpleEmailValidation(email)
  {
   var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
   
   if (filter.test(email))
   {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
  }
```